# insert 1 row with a lot of columns using an array in Perl DBI

Tags: arrays, perl, insert, dbi

I would like to insert a single row through perl dbi, but this row has A LOT of columns.
My query would be smt like this :

```
$sth->prepare("insert into bigtable (col1, col2, ..., col25) values (?, ?, ..., ?)");
$sth->execute($val1, $val2, ..., $val25);
```

But I want it cleaner. If I have an array, @myArray, containing these 25 variables, is there a way to do smt like this :

```
$sth->prepare("insert into bigtable (col1, col2, ..., col25) values (?, ?, ..., ?)");
$sth->execute(@myArray);
```

?

Comment: Did you try the second block of code? That should work. http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.618/DBI.pm#execute

Comment: I did, but got an error about hash references. I'll try it again tonight, and update the post. Thanks.

Comment: It's fixed, this was indeed correct, had an error somewhere else .. somehow. thanks anyway !

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
my $placeholders = join ", ", ("?") x @array;
$sth->prepare("insert into bigtable (col...) values ($placeholders)");
$sth->execute(@array);
```

Comment: And even `my $cols = join(', ', map { "col$_" } 1 .. @array);` if column names are exactly like in the question.

Comment: @mcsi Yep, and you don't even need curly braces: `map "col$_", 1..@array`